VR scene inspection. Xbox controller no longer functioning, can't move around
A while back, I woke up one day and my xbox controller no longer functioned in VR scene inspection. I can no longer move around any scene with the joysticks like I could before. I thought the controller itself was broken so I ordered a new one. Tried every USB port with both.
Nope, turns out it just changed itself on me in some way I'm at a total loss for ideas. I can't even begin to guess what's wrong. The controller is fine, I can confirm that.
I changed nothing, and did nothing. I literally was using it, it worked fine, then I went to bed. When I woke up it was completely broken. There's no error code from what I can see.

Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.
